# Why does array_contains accept columns for both arguments in SQL but not in Dataset API?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've been reviewing questions and answers about `array_contains` (and `isin`) methods on StackOverflow and I still cannot answer the following question:

Why does `array_contains` in SQL accept columns (references) as its arguments while the standard function does not?

I can understand that the above question could easily be marked as "primarily opinion-based" or similar so let me rephrase it to the following:

How to use `array_contains` standard function so it accepts arguments (the values) from columns?

```scala
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.3.0

val codes = Seq(
  (Seq(1, 2, 3), 2),
  (Seq(1), 1),
  (Seq.empty[Int], 1),
  (Seq(2, 4, 6), 0)).toDF("codes", "cd")
scala> codes.show
+---------+---+
|    codes| cd|
+---------+---+
|[1, 2, 3]|  2|
|      [1]|  1|
|       []|  1|
|[2, 4, 6]|  0|
+---------+---+

// array_contains in SQL mode works with arguments being columns
val q = codes.where("array_contains(codes, cd)")
scala> q.show
+---------+---+
|    codes| cd|
+---------+---+
|[1, 2, 3]|  2|
|      [1]|  1|
+---------+---+

// array_contains standard function with Columns does NOT work. Why?!
// How to change it so it would work (without reverting to SQL expr)?
scala> val q = codes.where(array_contains($"codes", $"cd"))
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName cd
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.array_contains(functions.scala:2988)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: Probably because in Hive, it is defined as `array_contains(Array<T>, value)` and that's how it was implemented back in [SPARK-8231](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8231)

Comment: plus it's not the only inconsistency between SQL mode and the DS API

Comment: For instance `substring` also has the same behaviour. You can use `substring(col , 0 , length(col) - 1)` but no with DSL

Comment: I mean for this specific case, spark convert the second argument into a Literal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the underlying function ArrayContains does take `expr` arguements you can always cheat a little bit.

```
scala> codes.where(new Column(ArrayContains($"codes".expr, $"cd".expr))).show
+---------+---+
|    codes| cd|
+---------+---+
|[1, 2, 3]|  2|
|      [1]|  1|
+---------+---+
**/
```

Like user9812147 said, the issue here is just that the SQL Parser is able to access the `ArrayContains` function directly. While it seems the direct function call forces the "values" portion to be treated as a Literal.

Comment: One more thing. array_contains is implemented using ArrayContains(Column for the first argument and a literal for the second)

Comment: This is really clever, Russ! I have never thought about using expressions this way.

Answer (score 5):

Simply because nobody cared enough to implement `(Column, Column) => Column` variant. If you check the source you'll see there is nothing in the design, that prohibits you from creating one, as standard workflow is to covert non-`Column` arguments to literals.

It is not even particularly distinctive. There are other functions which don't have wrappers taking additional `Column` argument, including, but not limited to, different date / time processing functions and mathematical functions.